# Cannot reset password for user

Tags: email, verification

I try to reset the password more than 5 times for one email.
After that, (for this user) this email box did not receive any reset emails from SF.
Email box - Gmail.
Where I can unlock this email for this user?
(other new emails adress works for this user) Thx

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you don't have delegated authentication enabled.

Is it a sandbox? Check that email deliverability (in settings) is not set to `No Access`

Also check that the email address is valid and does not have any suffix such as `.sandboxName`

Worse case scenario, just set him a password. Grab the user Id and execute anonymous...

```
System.setPassword('005WhateverUserId', 'TheNewPassword');
```

Keep in mind that the password must follow your password policies, and advise the user to change the password as soon as possible ;)

Also keep in mind that according to the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=resetting_and_expiring_passwords.htm&type=5)

> A user can request to reset a password through the forgot password link a maximum of five times in a 24-hour period. **Administrators can reset a user’s password as often as needed.**

Comment: Thx for your answer - It is on production

Comment: Deliverability - all email

Comment: Check - email is valid

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Did the user check the spam folder?

Comment: yes - first of all - thx for you answer

Comment: if I will use a new email box for this user - every think is correct. But after 5 attempts I do not receive any password reset emails.

Comment: no SSO no delegated authentication enabled

Comment: There is a limitation of 5 reset password requests / 24h (added the link to my post)

Answer (score 0):

please check the  Deliverability settings for your org.

Search for "Deliverability" in the quick find.

If the deliverability is set to "No Access" change it to "All email".

I hope this helps!

Comment: Deliverability settings - is already All email.

Comment: If you exceed maximum number of tries the user gets blocked for 24 hours. Please do check if the user is receiving the emails after 24 hours.